# Exception when creating an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, exc-bad-access

I am trying to debug an issue related to an NSArray. I am getting an exception:

EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_1386_GPFLT) at this line:

```
NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", "B", "C", nil];
```

This code is inside -(id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inside an NSView.

What is causing me to get this exception? I've Google-d the exception and I haven't found anyone else who gets it.

This project is for OS X and not iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument you're passing to `initWithObjects:` is an object (it's an instance of `NSString`), but the next two are not. It's illegal to insert non-object types into an Objective-C collection.

You need to prefix all of the string literals with `@` symbols to make them all objects, as shown below:

```
NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
```